# Get path of the folder inside servlet webapp directrory to store json files in that directory

Tags: java, servlets, neo4j

if i am giving the local directory path everything is working fine but when i am using  servletcontext method 
this line of code i am getting the exception 
 but i wanted to store generated json files on the server in the desired directory

```
    @PostConstruct
            private void getData() {
                createJsonFiles();
            }

public void useCaseCount() {

        count = 0;

        Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://124567:7687", AuthTokens.basic("user", "pass"));
        Session session = driver.session();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        String relativeWebPath = "/abc.json";
        String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);

        File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);
//      File file = new File("D:/project/ApplicationJ2EE/WebContent/abc.json");
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write("[");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      List<String> useCase_List = new ArrayList<>();


            StatementResult useCaseCount = tx.run(
                    "MATCH(use:Usecase)<-[r:UseCase_Is]-(e:News_Event) "
                            + "RETURN use.name as use_name, COUNT(r) AS count ORDER BY count(r)DESC LIMIT 5");

            while (useCaseCount.hasNext()) {
                Record useCaseCount_record = useCaseCount.next();
                try {
                    if (count == 0) {
                        writer.write("\n\t{ \n\t\t\"useCase\":" + useCaseCount_record.get("use_name") + ",\n\t\t\"count\":"
                                + useCaseCount_record.get("count") + "  \n\t}");
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        writer.write(",\n\t{\n\t\t\"useCase\":" + useCaseCount_record.get("use_name") + ",\n\t\t\"count\":"
                                + useCaseCount_record.get("count") + "  \n\t}");
                        count++;
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

            }

        try {
            writer.write("\n]");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
        }

    }

    error message 

        Jun 13, 2017 5:10:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet [DataAccessServlet] in web application [/IoTDEX] threw load() exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
        at iotdex.DAO.DataAccessServlet.useCaseCount(DataAccessServlet.java:463)
        at iotdex.DAO.DataAccessServlet.getData(DataAccessServlet.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.postConstruct(DefaultInstanceManager.java:203)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1061)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1000)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5212)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

web.xml entry

     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>DataAccessServlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>Application.DAO.DataAccessServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
```

Comment: I'm not a Java-specialist, but are you perhaps running into the fact that your artefact (jar, war) is not being expanded and thus does not have a path that you could write to ? For in that case getServletContext().getRealPath() does return null.

Comment: @TomGeudens i didn't get you what actually you are trying to say.Can you please ask with some explanation.

Comment: Hi. Just do a Google search with "getServletContext().getRealPath() return null". All the top results will explain that if the code you deploy is in a war/jar file that does not get expanded ... no path can be determined.

Comment: @TomGeudens ya but while we deploying our project in tomcat they will automatically do the extraction of your war file and creates the project in webapps directory